# Design Tab Missing

Tags: product, adminhtml, catalog, product-attribute

I do not see `Design` tab in my Catalog product edit page in admin end. I have searched in whole project but do not find it.

`1) From where the design tab is being added in product edit page ?`

`2) Could someone guide me on how to debug and recover if some tab is overriden or not seen ?`

P.S : I don't see `Design` group under my custom attribute set.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The design group is added by a Magento core set-up script `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/data/catalog_setup/data-install-1.6.0.0.php`. It is possible to delete these groups via the admin section, so I would suggest that someone has done this :(

You could either find a backup where the design group is still there or simply add it back via the admin or via a setup script of your own.

Be careful as you may then need to re-add all the attributes to this group. I am not 100% if you will need to, but you might.